# nginx multiple root config issue

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, config, centos7

I have the following nginx config for multiple root (`html/web` is default, `html/pma` is additional route):

```
server {

        listen 443 http2 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 http2 ssl;

        server_name  website.com;
        server_tokens off;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/web; 
        index index.php;

        location / {    
            try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ^~ /pma {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html; 

            location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files  $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
            }

        }   


        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files  $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

So, by default `/html/web/index.php` is opened, however `website.com/pma` opens `/html/pma/`, where `pma` is `PHPMyAdmin`.

The problem is:

PHPMyAdmin authentification form redirects to `index.php`. Therefore, when I write my credentials, it redirects me to `/html/web/index.php`! But should `/html/pma/index.php`. Even log out from PHPMyAdmin redirects to `/html/web/index.php`!

Could anyone suggest a better way of configuration?

Comment: I do not use PMA but have you set `PmaAbsoluteUri` to point to `/pma/`? See [this link](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#basic-settings).

Comment: move `index` outside of `location`s. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index

Comment: @Deadooshka Didn't help. Edited in question

Comment: @RichardSmith No, I haven't.

Comment: it chooses nested php `location` where the `root` isn't defined, so it seems you have to repeat that `root` inside the nested `location`.

Comment: @Deadooshka Copied to `root` in nested `location`. Didn't change anytthing

Comment: @RichardSmith You were right, PmaAbsoluteUri solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two errors in your configuration.

You `try_files` statement should end with `/index.php` or `=404`, not both! See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

The nested `location ~ \.php$` block will never be consulted. The outer `location ~ \.php$` block take precedence. You can solve this problem by using the `^~` modifier on the surrounding prefix `location`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details. For example:

```
location ^~ /pma {
    ...
    location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
    }
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check your answer. How do you suggest try_files to be written?

Comment: Assuming that the path `/index.php` always exists, the `=404` in the **first** `try_files` statement is redundant, use: `try_files $uri /index.php?$args`. I'm not convinced that the `$uri/` term helps at all - as it will work against your rewrite rule - its purpose is to add a trailing `/` if the directory exists.

Comment: Do you mean I should remove it at all?

Comment: Use: `try_files $uri /index.php?$args;`

Comment: Didn't change anything. I edited the question, removed the rewrites which could affect somehow